# Javascript function parameter length

Tags: javascript

Im trying to pass the following parameter trough a javascript function, but for some reason I got an empty value:

```
<td>
    <button type="button"  class="btn" 
        onclick="deletecontainer(c-328782ed70e322487380b6cec3c092ce)">
    </button>
</td>
```

### Javascript:

```
<script>
    function deletecontainer(str2) {
        alert(str2 + " Deleted");
    }
</script>
```

Is there any length on naming limitations?

Comment: `deletecontainer(c-328782ed70e322487380b6cec3c092ce)` is a syntax error, since `c-328782ed70e322487380b6cec3c092ce` is neither a string nor a valid identifier.

Comment: Please, don't use `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Which atribute do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass value to the function in the way you did it expect to find the value on the window. Since the value doe not exists you get `undefined`.

Change it to string and it will work

```
<button type="button"  class="btn" 
    onclick="deletecontainer('c-328782ed70e322487380b6cec3c092ce')">
</button>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Cool :-). Feel free to accept the answer and vote for it as well. appricated